# TFS 2013 with Octopus Deploy, Email Template - Resolved Bugs/User Stories

Tags: tfs, octopus-deploy

I've searched around and have not found a suitable solution for what I'm trying to accomplish.  Our environment uses TFS 2013 with TFS Build Definition configs.  Have also have Octopus Deploy for our deployments.  Octopus automatically deploys to our lower environments when a TFS build is queued.  The last octopus step in the process sends out an notification email when all is done and happy.

I want to implement in the EASIEST way possible the ability to have the email template step pick up the resolved bugs and/or user stories that were checked in for the current build.

Example Email

**Deployment of Fabikam 3.0.0.498 to QAServers**

Initiated by System at Wednesday, June 10, 2015 11:44:42 AM

Deployment process

The deployment included the following actions:

**• Deploy — Fabikam  version 3.0.0.498**

**• Fabikam Service Feed - Stop**

**• Fabikam Service - Deploy — Fabikam Service version 3.0.0.498**

**• Fabikam Service - Start**

**• Email Notification**

**Resolved Bugs:**

1234: Error loading page xyz, user/bgates

98787: Security on Claim Page is not hiding ssn for Data Analyst Role, user/hsimpson

**Resolved User Stories:**

2452: Implement async/await on from the api layer down to the repositories, user/dchang

44423: Change background from blue to pink for header, user/bgates

3456: Make the web app read my mind, user/god

Comment: Does the email step in Octopus have a pre/post script plugin entry points? If so use powershell script to query TFS for the bug information for your build (Octopus should expose the TFS build number as a variable you can use in power shell). Otherwise switch to VS Release Mgt :)

Comment: Yes, you can call into TFS Api to query the Work Items from powershell.  I've read about going this route but curious and wanted public feedback on the answer.

Comment: What's the alternative? As I said other than dropping Octopus in favour of Release Mgt..power shell is your way to go, it just works

Comment: Have you done this @sburgress123 or anything like it using TFS and Octopus?  We have 65+ dev/qa at our company, we cant just switch to Release Mgt...not really a practical answer.  Move on and thanks for the input.